# Read Fields from Non Editable PDF using iText7

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am attempting to read different PDF files using C# and iText. When the PDF is editable my code works and the fields and values are readable. However when the PDF is in a non-editable state no fields or keys are found using my code. Is there an additional step I need to take with iText to make the non-editable PDF readable?

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("nonedit.pdf"));
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);

IDictionary<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetFormFields();

var keys = fields.Keys;
var keysList = new List<object>();

foreach (var item in keys)
{
     keysList.Add(item);
}
```

Using this method finds no items in "keys" when reading a non-edit PDF.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention i'm using iText7 which I don't think uses that anymore.

Comment: You're right. I commented too quickly. My syntax was wrong. Thank you!

Comment: It depends on how the form is made non-editable. That can be done by setting each field read-only or it can be done flattening the form. In the former case you can still read the form fields, in the latter case, though, there is no form anymore, so you cannot read form field values. In such a case you may want to try text extraction.

Comment: Share a PDF then we could check for you. When the PDF form fields are readonly/hidden/invisible they can be read. If the document has been flattened however there is no chance to retrieve any form related structure.... (Except text extraction...)

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. I'll look into text extraction (never tried it before). There is no way to un-flatten a form, right? This is my first time dealing with PDF's so sorry for the ignorance.